# What's an effective way of getting all the keywords of a product in Magento?

Tags: magento

I couldn't find this documented in Magento Wiki and I didn't know exactly what database table or class in the `core/` folder it lies in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the object and use getMetaKeyword() on it. Note that categories use getMetaKeywords()

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku))

$_product->getMetaKeyword();
```

A faster method to load the object since SKU is a static attribute is to use

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sku,'sku');

$_product->getMetaKeyword();
```